# Less unrecognized input

Tags: css, less

I'm getting the error in the title with the below code inside a less file in visual studio 2012 ultimate using the latest version of web essentials

```
    .title {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;

    -webkit-text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #@basemessageColor;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #@basemessageColor;
}
```

this is the part that it's saying there is an error

```
-webkit-text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #@basemessageColor;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #@basemessageColor;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `baseMessageColor` just a color, and use

```
text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px @basemessageColor;
```

(`-webkit-text-shadow` hasn’t been necessary for quite a while, by the way.)